# Handsontable - Required Field

Tags: validation, handsontable

I have `handsontable` and I don't know what event that I need to validate a specific cell if its empty or not.

technically I have specific cell to be a required cell, if the cell is empty then it will call a callback or return false after executing a post.

I have used `beforeChange()` function before and I think it is not appropriate event for the issue.

Here's an [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgt7N.jpg).

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is use the `validator` option in the `columns` setting.

[Here](http://handsontable.com/demo/validation.html) is some more information on validators and an example but below is the code that would go with it.

```
emptyValidator = function(value, callback) {
    if (isEmpty(value)) { // isEmpty is a function that determines emptiness, you should define it
        callback(false);
    } else {
        callback(true);
    }
}
```

Then in the `columns` setting, supply each column and if that column should have all its cells be non-empty, supply this as the validator, just like they show in the handonstable example page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my work around: http://jsfiddle.net/Yulinwu/s6p39uje/

Firstly, you can add a custom property named `required` to the column settings.

```
  hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    ...
    columns: [{
    ...
    }, {
      type: 'numeric',
      format: '$ 0,0.00',
      required: true,   // Add a new setting named required
      validator: Handsontable.NumericValidator
    }]
  });
```

Then, you can add a listener to `beforeValidate` event using `addHook`, which returns false if a cell is required but empty.

```
  hot.addHook('beforeValidate', function(value, row, prop, source) {
    var ifRequired = this.getCellMeta(row, prop).required;
    console.log(ifRequired);
    if (ifRequired && value === '') {
      return false
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `allowEmpty:false` for that column like:-

```
 {
              data: 'EmpNo',
              type: 'numeric',
              allowInvalid: false,
              allowEmpty:false
              }
```

And in the setting of handsontable use `afterValidate` as below-

```
             afterValidate: function (isValid, value, row, prop, source) {
                    if (!isValid) {
                        $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled", true);
                        alert('Only non empty numbers are allowed');
                    }
                    else {
                            $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled", false);
                        }
                }
```